# LDAP search bootstrap example

Tags: java, scala, ldap

I'm trying to bootstrap some very simple LDAP code, connecting to a publicly available LDAP provider. However, even though the directory works fine in Apache DS, my code doesn't find any objects.

```
import javax.naming._
import javax.naming.directory._
import javax.naming.ldap._
import java.util._
val env = new Hashtable[String, Object]()
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none")
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.virginia.edu:389/o=University of Virginia,c=US")
var ctx = new InitialDirContext(env)

val searchControls = new SearchControls()
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE)
```

Now no matter how I try to search or lookup, eg.

```
var results = ctx.search("o=University of Virginia,c=US", "(cn=*)", searchControls)
```

or more specifically

```
var results = ctx.search("ou=adagn, ou=Business Non-Degree-adagn, o=University of Virginia, c=US", "(cn=*)", searchControls)
```

I just get a `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'ou=adagn, ou=Business Non-Degree-adagn, o=University of Virginia, c=US'`.

I don't even know if the base is wrong or the search expression is wrong...?

EDIT: This works:

```
ldapsearch -h ldap.virginia.edu -p 389 -s sub -b 'o=University of Virginia,c=US' -x -z 1 '(cn=*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with the following modification:

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.virginia.edu:389")
```